# Optimize joining two big tables ORACLE 19C

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, oracle19c

how can I optimize the query below :

```
 SELECT  A.CNACT, A.FACML, A.LCACT, H.CAECH, H.CMECH, H.MCCMP,H.DAHIS,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY H.CNACT,H.CAECH,H.CMECH ORDER BY H.DAHIS DESC) RK
 FROM NATACF A,HISTER H WHERE A.CNACT = H.CNACT;

select count (*)   FROM NATACF;  -->74794
select count (*)   FROM HISTER;  -->2100720
```

you find in attachment the execution plan [image: Execution Plan]

Thank you.
As you see window sort and hash JOIN are not optimised effectively. What is the best way to optimise this?

the screenshot below of prod database :[image: Execution plan from prod]

Comment: ANY HELP PLEASE

Comment: You join all rows from both tables. I suppose that full table scans and a hash join are indeed the fastest method to do this. Then you want to calculate ranks, so you need a sorting of the rows. Looks just fine to me.

Comment: On a side note: When was this query written? It's using the old join syntax of the 1980s. You may want to change this to `FROM natcaf a INNER JOIN hister h ON h.cnact = a.cnact` for readability.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it look good but when we call it from the applicative it's take 5hours I attached the screenshot

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns `A.CNACT` and `H.CNACT` ?

Comment: Is the first number in your second screenshot rows and the second number bytes? Are you reading 198,000,000 rows from the HISTER table mounting up to 5.5 GB and taking 52 minutes? And wonder why the complete query takes so long to run? If reading one table alone needs so much IO and so much space that the system is probably swapping memory pages all the time, how can it be surprising that the query takes long? Reading the table is a small task compared to joining the rows or sorting them. What for are you selecting so many rows? Are you trying to export the database?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you want *ALL* data from *both" tables - no filtering in place.

- Oracle reads whole smaller (driving) table into hash map.
- Uses joining column CNACT as a key
- They reads whole bigger table and performs lookup in the hashmap for each row read.
- the complexity is O(N+M), each row is read only once

There is no way to evaluate such a query in faster way (aside from dirty tricks like putting both tables into CLUSTER, pinning tables in buffer cache,...).

PS: it is strange that explain plan shows 2 sec - both tables are not actually so big.
While prod DB says 5hours.
Try to execute the query using `set timing on set echo off set pagesize 0 set termout off set feedback off set pause off set verify off set headings off`. Basically read the whole result and then discard it and print exec. time. And you will see.

Maybe it is the app (or network) who has problem to transfer the whole big result set. Is such a case you would see "SQL*Net Message to client" wait event in AWR. Like the database is waiting for the application to accept more data. Like you are sending about 14GB of data into the application.

For example Java has problems with GC, or each row is used to costly Java Object creation.

Answer (score 0):

we resolved the problem using the with :

```
WITH Z AS(SELECT
       |     X.DATRA,X.COINI,X.COINT,X.NUCPT,N.COBCN,X.CNACT,N.LCACT,N.CNACR,DECODE(X.CSOPT,NULL,X.CAECH,O.CAECR) CAECH,
       |     DECODE(X.CSOPT,NULL,X.CMECH,O.CMECR) CMECH,X.CSOPT,X.MTSNA,N.COTSJ,X.CSENS,X.QTCCP,D.TXCHA,R.MAINT,X.CODEV,
       |     D.CDVRF,C.TYEDI,C.NUSES
   10: |     FROM CUMPOR X,
       |          MRXIDE C,.....
```

**The WITH clause - The materialized subquery data is persistent through the query.**